# Wordpress plugins are not working after moving site to server

Tags: wordpress

When i am uploading my wordpress site on server all the plugins are not working. when i am going to wp-admin, i have to deactivate all plugins and after that when again i am activating plugins then plugings are working. and also i have to set all the contents of plugin again on server end. I did research but did not get any help. I am not getting now how to fix this. i want when i am uploading site from localhost to server all the plugins woking same as in localhost and i dont have to reset again on server end. Please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't upload your local Database[SQL file] to your live server. Upload the local DB file and make the required changes like the site url and any other localhost path to server path.

Answer (score 0):

you should do

1- export your db from server 1
2- open it in an editor find wp_options 
3- move little bit down when you find wp_options here you see a url of server 1
4- using replace all, replace that url with new url.
5- save fime 
6- import it on the server 2.

Done.

Note: only text widgets will not have data in  them you will need to add that data again. and also update the permalink again on server 2